# Issues Connecting Client from MicroPython to Raspberry Pi Pico Server

Tags: sockets, socket.io, micropython, python-sockets, raspberry-pi-pico

I have been trying to develop an IoT-based application. I thought using WebSockets with my Raspberry Pi Pico W as the server would be a good idea to transfer information to my react application in real-time. I am new to socket programming and I am having issues transferring information between the React App and the Pico W. For some more context, my Server side code looks like the following:

```
addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(addr)
s.listen(1)

print('Listening On ' + str(addr))

while True:
    try:
        cl,addr = s.accept()
        print('Client connected from ' + str(addr))
        cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        cl.send("Hello")
        time.sleep(3)
        cl.close()
    except:
        cl.close()
        break
```

In React Native Client-side code looks like follows:

```
import io from "socket.io-client"
import {useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket_2 = io("http://<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>:80")
    socket_2.emit('message', 'data');
    socket_2.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    console.log(socket_2)
  }, []);
```

The interesting thing is that I am sure the server side is working because when I connect from the browser is sends me the "Hello" response. Additionally when I connect from React App I see a bunch of logs in Python Resembling the following:

```
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62518)
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62540)
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62541)
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62554)
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62567)
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62573)
Client connected from ('<IP_ADDRESS_NOT_SHOWN_HERE>', 62580)
```

To sum it up there are two primary things I am questioning here.

1-) I am not sure why it keeps making new connections

2-) I am also not sure why my information is not being transferred in between React Native and my Raspberry Pi Pico W server properly

Any help would be appreciated I am a socket-programming noob :/

I have tried using Socket IO and also I have tried using the react native socket library. I believe the socket io is much easier but I just cannot understand what is happening here

Answer (score 0):

Here, you just accept connection, you are **not** doing anything with received message from your React application, you send response an close connection. Its not how websockets works

this explains both of your questions: why you get new connection each time (you close connection) and why it does not work properly (its not proper WS server implementation)

<strike>As far as I know it- micropython does not have proper WS implementation.</strike> Here is something about websockets (no experience, just decided to share)

https://github.com/marcidy/micropython-uasyncio-websockets

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microdot/tree/main/examples/websocket

You need to get down to very basics, study WS protocol and implement it if you want to have web sockets available in your pico.

Extremely simplified WS pseodocode:

- accept connection
- while new messages available

  - read message and send response
  - wait for messages
- close connection when connection breaks